# Linker cannot find strnstr() on Ubuntu with libbsd

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, static-linking

To port some existing code from FreeBSD to Ubuntu (22.04) with the libbsd-dev package installed, I am encountering a problem in the linking phase: `undefined reference to 'strnstr'`. Code:

```
#include <bsd/string.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char * ppl = "World citizens";

    char * s = strnstr(ppl, "c", strlen(ppl));

    printf("Hello, %s\n", s);
}
```

The command used for building and linking is: `cc -lbsd test-strnstr.c`. This command invokes gcc.

If called explicitly with clang (`clang -lbsd test-strnstr.c`) it works. It also compiles, links and runs fine on MacOS (without the 'bsd/' part in the first #include).

What can be the reason that it won't link with the `strnstr()` in libbsd (and libbsd.a is installed /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's because the **order of libraries** when linking with **GCC**. So I think you need to ensure that the order of libraries is correct.

Try `cc test-strnstr.c -lbsd`

Remember. the linker searches from left to right. The library that needs symbols must be first, then the library that resolves the symbol.

Comment: Fixed it immediately. Interesting little difference with Clang!